# Arrays in MASM Assembly (very confused beginner)

Tags: arrays, visual-studio, loops, assembly

I have a pretty basic question:
How do you populate arrays in assembly? In high level programming languages you can use a for-loop to set a value to each index, but I'm not sure of how to accomplish the same thing assembly. I know this is wrong, but this is what I have:

```
ExitProcess PROTO
.data
warray WORD 1,2,3,4
darray DWORD ?

.code
main PROC
mov edi, OFFSET warray
mov esi, OFFSET darray
mov ecx, LENGTHOF warray


L1:
mov ax, [edi]          ;i want to move a number from warray to ax
movzx esi,ax           ;i want to move that number into darray...
add edi, TYPE warray   ;this points to the next number?

    loop L1 

    call ExitProcess
main ENDP
END
```

Each time the loop runs, ax will be overwritten with the value of the array's index, right? Instead how do I populate darray with the array elements from warray? Any help would be very much appreciated...I'm pretty confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than one way to populate an array and your code is almost working. One way is to use counter in the indirect address so you don't have to modify destination and source array pointers each loop:

```
ExitProcess PROTO
.data
    warray WORD 1,2,3,4
    darray DWORD 4 dup (?) ; 4 elements

.code
main PROC
    mov edi, OFFSET warray
    mov esi, OFFSET darray
    xor ecx, ecx                ; clear counter
L1:
    mov ax, [edi + ecx * 2]     ; get number from warray
    movzx [esi + ecx * 4], ax   ; move number to darray
    inc ecx                     ; increment counter
    cmp ecx, LENGTHOF warray
    jne L1 

    call ExitProcess
main ENDP
END
```

Of course this code could be modified to fill the array backwards to possibly save couple of bytes like you probably meant to do in your original code. Here is another way that has more compact loop:

```
ExitProcess PROTO
.data
    warray WORD 1,2,3,4
    darray DWORD 4 dup (?) ; 4 elements

.code
main PROC
    mov edi, OFFSET warray
    mov esi, OFFSET darray
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF warray - 1    ; start from end of array
L1:
    mov ax, [edi + ecx * 2]     ; get number from warray
    movzx [esi + ecx * 4], ax   ; move number to darray
    loop L1 

    ; get and set element zero separately because loop terminates on ecx = 0:
    mov ax, [edi]
    movzx [esi], ax

    call ExitProcess
main ENDP
END
```

You should also note that when working with arrays of the same type you can do simple copy very efficiently using repeat prefix with instructions like [MOVSD](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_203.html):

```
ExitProcess PROTO
.data
    array1 DWORD 1,2,3,4
    array2 DWORD 4 dup (?)

.code
main PROC
    mov esi, OFFSET array1      ; source pointer in esi
    mov edi, OFFSET array2      ; destination in edi
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF array1    ; number of dwords to copy
    cld                         ; clear direction flag so that pointers are increasing
    rep movsd                   ; copy ecx dwords
    call ExitProcess
main ENDP
END
```

Comment: You need a `movzx` load and a `mov` store, not the other way around.  `movzx` only exists with a register destination.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not "supposed to know" this, but anyway, there were (way back when) an instruction and an instruction prefix that were made to do exactly this.

Take a look here at this Microsoft page:  [HERE (click on it)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561504(v=vs.85).aspx)

On that page scroll down until you find this phrase...

"...*These instructions are remnants of the x86's CISC heritage and in recent processors are actually slower than the equivalent instructions written out the long way.*..."

What you do is...

- Put the size of the array in `Ecx`
- Point `Edi` at the start of the arry
- Use the appropriate string instruction to populate it

The syntax (Masm/Tasm/etc.) will probably look something like this...

```
 Mov       Ecx, The_Length_Of_The_Array            ;Figure this out somehow
 Lea       Edi, The_Target_You_Want_To_Fill        ;Define this somewhere
```

Now, if you want to copy from one place to another, do this...

```
 Lea       Esi, The_Source_You_Want_To_Copy         ;Whatever, define it
 Cld                                                ;This is the direction flag, make it inc
 Rep       Movsb                                    ;Movsb means move byte for byte
```

Now, if you want to stuff the same value in each byte in the arrray do this...

```
 Mov       AL, The_Value_You_Want_To_Stuff          ;Define this to your liking
 Cld                                                ;This is the direction flag, make it inc
 Rep       Stosb                                    ;Stosb means store AL into each byte
```

Again, these instructions are, for reasons others will elucidate, not cool anymore and if you use them you will get cooties or something.

There are also string instructions for comparison, "Scanning", "Loading", and so on. They were once quite useful (and still are, but the "modern" gang today won't admit it) particularly with the `Rep` prefix added to them.

If this helps, but you need more detail, feel free to ask.

Comment: They're not as bad as you make them out to be. They used to be pretty poorly implemented, but on newer architectures (SNB+) they're actually pretty fast. They're not a complete replacement for macro instructions yet, but there are a few cases in which they perform better than hand written assembly.

Comment: @drivingon9 Totally agree with you. Write them in the right way (a ridiculous play on words, I suppose) and they will accomplish what few other instructions can do. It just seems that, nowadays, the string instructions have been labeled as generally not cool. Stupid ? Indeed ! But, that's life today.

Comment: Lost the editing window time. @drivingon9 plus one for your comment and I edited my answer.

Comment: `repne scasb` (memchr) and `repe cmpsb` (memcmp) are only useful for code-size, not performance.  Fast-strings and ERMSB microcode only speeds up `rep stos` and `rep movs`, not the conditional rep search instruction. They're very slow, like 2 cycles per compare for `repe cmpsb`, on modern x86 (e.g. Skylake), so about 32x slower than a good SSE2 `pcmpeqb` for large arrays, not even AVX2. Also not very good for short arrays; they have some startup overhead.  `lodsd` or `lodsq` without rep is occasionally worth using on Haswell and later (only 2 uops, same as mov-load + add), but others are worse